# Live search filter knockout js with nested level

Tags: search, knockout.js, filter

I have got an idea about how to do with live search filter function in Knockout.js.  But I have new kind of complex requirement that final output would be looks like below...

[image]

When user clicks on listed out search results,  he might have another set of children list which should have 'n' number of drill downs!

I tried with simple live search filter function.  I have lost something.  I dont know how to load multilevel data from Json and how to make bind this in knockout JS.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/67kgm/ -  this is the url i started off.  But i dont know how to load nested level of data as I put illustration in my question.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564936/knockoutjs-recurring-array/25565664#25565664) recursion is going to help

Comment: Best easy example for nesting in [KO documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html#live-example-nested-children). As for the JSON, use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon similar issue. It's important to understand, how Knockout detects which observable value affect computed one. I noticed, that in all examples, observables are invoked in computed function scope. While computed wasn't updated if I invoked it on filter function (sub-scope). I tried invoking them in the beginning of computed function, so that filtering function has access to values through variables in the same scope. This seems to work, and each time observable changed — computed updated.

Here I modified your computed, which filters all fields live.

```
self.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function () {
    var idSearch = self.idSearch(),
        nameSearch = self.nameSearch().toLowerCase(),
        townSearch = self.townSearch();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.records(), function (r) {
        return r.id.toString().indexOf(idSearch) !== -1 &&
            r.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(nameSearch) !== -1 &&
            (r.homeTown === townSearch || townSearch === "");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67kgm/127/